# Typescript:error TS2377: Constructors for derived classes must contain a 'super' call

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, constructor, angular7

I am Trying to implement this [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-upload-file-with-progress-bar) of angular-upload-file-with-progress-bar but in my code

```
export class UploadDocumentTemplateComponent extends FieldType {}
```

I have this line because of it I'm getting this error

**error TS2377: Constructors for derived classes must contain a 'super' call.**

how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is that all your code for `UploadDocumentTemplateComponent` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just in constructor you need

```
constructor()
{
   super()
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To provide a bit of a more complete answer or an explanation to why you do the above answer, the word `super` is a reference to the super class or the parent class of `UploadDocumentTemplateComponent` which is `FieldType`.

You don't show here if you called the constructor of the child class, but whenever you do, it's required to call the constructor method of the parent as well.

And you do it like this:

```
export class UploadDocumentTemplateComponent extends FieldType {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

Again for more completions' sake. Even when you pass in `super();` you might still see an error especially if you have the following:

```
class FieldType {
  constructor(public color: string) {}
}

class UploadDocumentTemplateComponent extends FieldType {
  constructor() {
    super():
  }
}
```

At which point you resolve that like so:

```
class FieldType {
  constructor(public color: string) {}
}

class UploadDocumentTemplateComponent extends FieldType {
  constructor() {
    super('red'):
  }
}
```

But chances are you don't want to do that, chances are we want the `color` to still come in as an argument to your `UploadDocumentTemplateComponent` when you create it.

So maybe we can take in an argument to the `UploadDocumentTemplateComponent` constructor function like so:

```
class FieldType {
  constructor(public color: string) {}
}

class UploadDocumentTemplateComponent extends FieldType {
  constructor(color: string) {
    super('red'):
  }
}
```

Now another detail to pay attention to is the access modifier, so notice in this example I did not add a `public` modifier. I did not put the `public` keyword on because we do not want to reassign or create a new field in `UploadDocumentTemplateComponent` of `color`, the field `color` belongs to `FieldType` in my example.

That's why I did not put on the modifier of `public`.

Now we call the parent class constructor with the super class here and we are not going to pass in the hard coded red, instead we can pass in the color like so:

```
class FieldType {
  constructor(public color: string) {}
}

class UploadDocumentTemplateComponent extends FieldType {
  constructor(color: string) {
    super(color):
  }
}
```